# How to insert a blob data in Oracle to a column in SQL Server with Image datatype

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, blob

I collected a image data from Oracle using linked server in SQL.
That data looks like this

[image: Blob data]

When I tried to insert same data to my SQL Server into an Image datatype column it is getting inserted. But inserted value is completely different.

Kindly give me a query to insert blob data to SQL Server. Do I need to convert it?

Here is my insert query

```
insert into ICCS_Signature_INW_Test (AccountNumber, Image)
values ('123456789',IMAGE DATA)
```

[image: SQL Queries]

Comment: You can try to use a different data type on the SQL Server side: `VARBINARY(MAX)`

Comment: I tried with both Varbinary(max) and Image datatype.

Comment: https://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/save-image-to-database-table-in-sql-server.aspx

Comment: Please show your SQL Statement(s) which carry out this select/insert.

Comment: @DaleK  Insert query added

Comment: How does `IMAGE_DATA` get populated? You say it comes from a linked server query? There is no linked server there? Are you stored it temporarily in a variable? We need to see all that stuff.

Comment: @DaleK This is my Linked server select query  select * from ECheque...VW_SIGNATURE.

Comment: @DaleK From this result am taking the image value and try to insert in SQL table.Trying to insert value hardcoded.

Comment: Please show us (in your question) *exactly* the query you are trying to use... (just truncate the data).

Comment: And then show us the select you are using, and the data that is showing where you say it is *completely different*

Comment: Oh yes, as as already mentioned (although this is not your issue), `image` is being depreciated, you should be using `varbinary(max)`.

Comment: @DaleK I added the queries in question .I compare the two data which i took from linked server and inserted data .There are lot of differences in both.Data which i collected from Linked server contains 65536 characters.But when i insert the same only 43677 characters are saving and there is difference in both.

Comment: Do you have an insert trigger on the `ICCS_Signature_INW_Test` table that's modifying the `IMAGE` column? The data isn't completely different, but it does seem to have 4-bits of 0x0 inserted at the beginning so there's something odd happening.

Comment: Can you paste in *as text* the exact query you are using to insert, along with the output you are getting and what you expect. I can't see any difference from the images